# Difference equation corresponds to $y''=-y$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

> Convert the differential equation $y''=-y$ into a difference equation using the leapfrog method.

My reference says:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\\Delta t&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}Y_{n+1}\\Y_{n+1}^{'}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&\Delta t\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}Y_{n}\\Y_{n}^{'}\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}Y_{n+1}\\Y_{n+1}^{'}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&\Delta t\\-\Delta t&1-(\Delta t)^2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}Y_{n}\\Y_{n}^{'}\end{bmatrix}\\
Y_{n+1}=Y_n+\Delta t.Y_n^{'}\implies Y_{n+1}-Y_n=\Delta t.Y_n^{'} \\
\Delta t.Y_{n+1}+Y_{n+1}^{'}=Y_n^{'} \implies Y_n^{'}-Y_{n+1}^{'}=\Delta t.Y_{n+1}
$$
Looks like the first equation is obtained by taking forward difference and later by backward. How do I justify such a choice ?

**My Attempt**

$$
Y_n^{'}=\frac{Y_{n+1}-Y_{n-1}}{2\Delta t}\\
Y_{n}^{''}=\frac{Y_{n+1}^{'}-Y_{n-1}^{'}}{2\Delta t}=\frac{\frac{Y_{n+2}-Y_{n}}{2\Delta t}-\frac{Y_{n}-Y_{n-2}}{2\Delta t}}{2\Delta t}=\frac{Y_{n+2}-2Y_{n}+Y_{n-2}}{(2\Delta t)^2}=\frac{Y_{n+1}-2Y_{n}+Y_{n-1}}{(\Delta t)^2}=-Y_{n}\\
\boxed{Y_{n+1}=Y_{n-1}+2\Delta t.Y_{n}^{'}\\
Y_{n+1}^{'}=Y_{n-1}^{'}-2\Delta t.Y_{n}}
$$
$$
Y_{n-1}=(2-(\Delta t)^2)Y_n-Y_{n+1}\implies Y_{n+1}=(2-(\Delta t)^2)Y_n-Y_{n+1}+2\Delta t.Y_{n}^{'}\\
\boxed{Y_{n+1}=\frac{(2-(\Delta t)^2)}{2}Y_n+\Delta t.Y_n^{'}}
$$

How do I approach this and obtain the matrix difference equation corresponds to $y''+y=0$ using midpoint differences ?

**Reference:** Example 3-Difference Equations (Page 323) and Q.28 Problem Set 6.3 (Page 335), Chapter 6 : Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors
, [Introduction to Linear Algebra, Gilbert Strang, Fifth Edition (2016)](http://math.mit.edu/%7Egs/linearalgebra/)

Answer (score 1):

The equation you get for $Y_{n+1}$ is the same as what [Wikipedia says for the Leapfrog Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration#Algorithm):

$$Y_{n+1} = Y_n + Y_n' \Delta t + 0.5 (-Y_n) \Delta t^2$$
while the update equation for $Y'_{n+1}$ should be according to Wikipedia:
\begin{align}
Y'_{n+1} &= Y'_n + 0.5 (-Y_n -Y_{n+1}) \Delta t \\
&= Y'_{n-1} + 0.5 (-Y_{n-1} -Y_{n}) \Delta t + 0.5 (-Y_n -Y_{n+1}) \Delta t \\
&=Y_{n-1}' +0.5(-Y_{n-1} -2Y_{n} -Y_{n+1}) \Delta t
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

In the leapfrog Verlet method the grid for the velocities is shifted by a half-step. Then the equations for position and velocity are just midpoint or central Euler formulas
$$
Y_{n+1}-Y_n=Δt\,Y'_{n+1/2},\\
Y'_{n+1/2}-Y'_{n-1/2}=Δt\,A(Y_n)=Δt\,(-Y_n),
$$
which gives exactly the equations you cited.